# regex not working for phone number field

Tags: javascript, regex

i have one phone number text-field.Now,i want to apply regex through java-script. for that i used below code.but it is not accept 10 digit.would any told me that what is wrong with below code.

java script code:-

```
function val(value) {
    var p = phonevalue1
    p = p.replace(/[^\d]*/gi, "")
    if (p.length <= 5) {
        value.value = p;
    }
    else if (p.length > 5 && p.length < 9) {
        var a = p.substring(0, 5);
        var b = p.substring(5, p.length);
        var c = a + "-" + b;
        value.value = c;
    }

    else if (p.length >= 9) {
        var len = p.length;
        var a = p.substring(0, 5);
        var b = p.substring(5, len);
        var c = a + "-" + b;
        value.value = c.substring(0, 10);
    }
}
```

Comment: why `ig` both  _p = p.replace(/[^\d]*/gi, "")_

Comment: it is regex a pattern.

Comment: What is the issue? Try to specify what was the expected result and what you got instead.

Comment: What is "phonevalue1" supposed to be? value?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell you want the following

1. 5 or less digits just add digits to **value** property of **value** object
2. 6 - 8 digits add hyphen after fifth digit as in **12345-678**
3. 9 digits or greater **12345-6789**

NOTES:

value.value means **value** is an {};

phonevalue1 is undefined in the function, so I will assume it is defined in the parent scope and is some string of numbers.

The code you have provided can be simplified a bit. I will make some adjustments and you'll have to adjust how your code block handles the function. K?

```
function val(value) {
  var p = phonevalue1
  p = p.replace(/[^\d]*/gi, "")
  if (p.length <= 5) {
    value.value = p;
  }
  else if (p.length > 5 && p.length < 9) {
    var a = p.substring(0, 5);
    var b = p.substring(5, p.length);
    var c = a + "-" + b;
    value.value = c;
  }

  else if (p.length >= 9) {
    var len = p.length;
    var a = p.substring(0, 5);
    var b = p.substring(5, len);
    var c = a + "-" + b;
    value.value = c.substring(0, 10);
  }
}
```

Change to this...

**NOTE:** Where **value** is your object as you stated,

```
var value = {};
var phonevalue1 = "12345";
var phonevalue2 = "12345678";
var phonevalue3 = "1234567890";

value.value = phonevalue1.replace(/(^\d{5})/, "$1-").replace(/-$/, '');
=> { value: "12345" };

value.value = phonevalue2.replace(/(^\d{5})/, "$1-").replace(/-$/, '');
=> { value: "12345-678" };

value.value = phonevalue3.replace(/(^\d{5})/, "$1-").replace(/-$/, '');
=> { value: "12345-67890" };
```

> If you want to use a function as you have, I will try to make the same thing work, but the way your code is structured is not recommended as it is unnecessarily long and confusing.

```
function addHyphen( numString ){
  return numString.replace(/(^\d{5})/, "$1-").replace(/-$/, '');
}

value.value = addHyphen( phonevalue1 );
```

Hope this helps...